# Non-default location for ssh config file in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

How can I tell `ssh` to look for config file in a location other than the default one: `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **-F** *configfile*
>
> Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file. If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (*/etc/ssh/ssh_config*) will be ignored. The default for the per-user configuration file is *~/.ssh/config*.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Comment: This works but every time I need to enter the config file path. Is it possible to store this option as default somewhere?

Comment: @motam79 quoting: "[...] the system-wide configuration file (*/etc/ssh/ssh_config*) will be ignored.". Without system-wide file, you can't store this anywhere. (**This is my own assumption without any hard evidence and testing!**)

Comment: @motam79 If you're only starting ssh manually from the command line, you can make a shell alias. If you use other stuff (scripts, binaries, whatever) that look for ssh on the path, you could drop a wrapper script somewhere that has a higher priority than the real binary.

Answer (score 7):

As of OpenSSH 7.3p1, you can Include other config files in ssh_config.

So, you could add to /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Include ~/custom_ssh.conf
```

Don't think this will stop the default ~/.ssh/config from being loaded, however.